# How to show Image in React Native app in OS default viewer?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have React Native app where I want to show full image to user. I do not want to make my own non-native image viewer and I want to use default Android/iOS viewer for that.

Is it possible to click on thumbnail in React Native app and open image in OS native viewer (or open popup to select one of compatible viewers)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-viewer. It uses `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` on Android and `QuickLook` framework on iOS.